# ASP.NET CORE Hosting - Error Internal Server Error Handler "aspNetCore" has a bad module "AspNetCoreModule" in its module list

Tags: asp.net-core, hosting, nopcommerce, internal-server-error, nopcommerce-4.0

I'm hosting ASP.NET Core 2 site and getting below error message.

```
HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "aspNetCore" has a bad module "AspNetCoreModule" in its module list
```

My application is using nopCommerce 4.00  and server side already ASP.NET Core component is installed.

Comment: Where you trying to hosting? shared? VPS? Is that specific with nopCommerce app or also with a simple Core app?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I was facing the same issue after [following this blog](https://stackify.com/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-to-iis/) on how to host an asp.net core app into IIS. Visual studio had added the following web.config in the published output folder.

[image]

Then I looked into my IIS module to check if the .NET core hosting bundle was installed properly and I saw this,

[image]

So I changed the module in web.config,

```
<handlers>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
```

and it worked without any issues after that.

Comment: this worked for me but every time I published the solution from Visual Studio it set the web.config back to modules="AspNetCoreModule" again. Since this was just a test project, I updated to the latest versions of Visual Studio and .Net core, deleted the whole project and started again and after that it worked.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much!

@Andy, I think since I am far along in my solution I will have to manually update the web.config every single time :/  Not a big deal but certainly tedious.  Hey, now I know for my next .NET Core project!

Comment: If you don't want to manually change the web.config every time, installing an older version of the IIS hosting bundle also installs the "AspNetCoreModule" which can be installed side-by-side with V2. I installed the .Net Core 2.2 IIS hosting bundle which did it for me.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error. The handler was `AspNetCoreModule`, code is `%SystemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\aspnetcore.dll`. Changing the handler to `AspNetCoreModuleV2` with code `%ProgramFiles%\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll` solved the problem.

[image]

[image]

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/troubleshooting-http-error-500.21-internal-server-error-aspnetcore-handler) is also helpful. In case the link doesn't work:

> This error can occur if the [**AspNetCoreModule**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is not installed properly in IIS on the computer that is running the Microsoft Dynamics NAV Web Server components. The AspNetCoreModule is installed with the Microsoft .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle. You can get this error if this has been not been fully installed or the installation has been damaged in some way.
>
> To resolve this issue, open Programs and Features in Control Panel and check whether Microsoft .NET Core Windows Server Hosting is installed. Then, try one of the following:
>
> - If it is installed, repair it from Programs and Features, by
>     selecting it, choosing Change, and then choosing Repair.
> - If it is not installed, download and install Microsoft .NET Core -
>     Windows Server Hosting bundle.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. In my case the Module had AspNetCoreModuleV2 key with correct value, but aspNetCore in Handler Mapping did not have the correct value.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same error, I enabled the logs in web.config file by settinig **stdoutLogEnabled="true"**

```
<aspNetCore processPath=".\site01.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

And I found that I am missing the correct version of **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App**

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.12' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      3.1.2 at [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
```

so i installed the **ASP.NET Core 2.1 Runtime (v2.1.16) - Windows Hosting Bundle Installer** from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1/runtime/?utm_source=getdotnetcore&utm_medium=referral

**AND MY PROBLEM WAS SOLVED.**

Comment: This solution saved me from having to change my web.config everytime that I re-published from VS, which was an issue mentioned in another comment.

Comment: Excellent  Solution, thanks very much, it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same error,I change "AspNetCoreModule" to "AspNetCoreModuleV2" in web.config. work fine

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the issue that I was having.

I have posted a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62338846/1846266), which solves a different scenario.

After installing the *.NET Core Windows Hosting Bundle*, and even the SDK, the *AspNetCoreModule* lines were still missing on `applicationHost.config`.

*AspNetCoreModuleV2* was there, though.

So, I found an `applicationHost.config` in another server that had those *AspNetCoreModule* lines and updated the file on the broken server. Not sure why they were not being added by the .NET Core installation on that specific server.

I added the line below under the `<globalModules>` section:

`<add name="AspNetCoreModule" image="%SystemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\aspnetcore.dll" />`

And this one under `<modules>`:

`<add name="AspNetCoreModule" />`

Hope this helps.