# Error 500.19 with 0x8007000d when running ASP.NET Core app in IIS despite AspNetCoreModule being installed

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core app that runs great in IIS Express.  Similarly, if I launch the app from the command line via `dotnet run`, everything works smoothly:

```
C:\Code\Sandbox\IisTestApp\IisTestApp>dotnet run
Using launch settings from C:\Code\Sandbox\IisTestApp\IisTestApp\Properties\launchSettings.json...
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\Code\Sandbox\IisTestApp\IisTestApp
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

If I try to target local IIS, I get the following error:

> Unable to start process C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe. The web server request failed with status code 500, Internal Server Error. The full response has been written to C:\Users{my user name}\AppData\Local\Temp\HttpFailure_08-05-50.html.

The HTML file contains this information:

[image: Screenshot of 500.19 error]

> ## HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> **The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.**
>
> **Detailed Error Information:**
>
> **Module**       IIS Web Core
>   **Notification**     BeginRequest
>   **Handler**      Not yet determined
>   **Error Code**       0x8007000d
>   **Config Error**
>   **Config File**      \?\C:\Code\Sandbox\IisTestApp\IisTestApp\web.config
>   **Requested URL**    http://localhost:80/IisTestApp
>   **Physical Path**    C:\Code\Sandbox\IisTestApp\IisTestApp
>   **Logon Method**     Not yet determined
>   **Logon User**       Not yet determined

*Note: in case it's not obvious from that message, this is a minimal repro of my problem, not the actual app*

Most of what I see online says that the error code `0x8007000d` indicates that I don't have the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting component (`AspNetCoreModule`), but I definitely have installed that:

[image: screenshot of add remove programs with hosting component installed]

I can also see it in the main "Modules" page of IIS, and verified that the file it points to actually exists:

[image: Screenshot of modules list in IIS]

Strangely, if I try to go to the Modules page for this specific site, I get the same error message as the web page:

> There was an error while performing this operation.
>
> Details:
>
> Filename: \?\C:\Code\Sandbox\IisTestApp\IisTestApp\web.config
>   Error:

[image: Screenshot of site modules error]

This hosting module version (2.1.8) matches generally what I have installed:

```
C:\Users\{my user name}>dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.504 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

C:\Users\{my user name}>dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

And what my test app is targeting:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Despite all that, I think the problem really is related to IIS and that hosting component!  Here is the (very default) web.config that is generated with the project template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="bin\IISSupport\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" arguments="-argFile IISExeLauncherArgs.txt" stdoutLogEnabled="false">
        <environmentVariables />
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

*Note: I still get the same error message if I hardcode the full path in the processPath, or use `.\` relative pathing*

If I remove the `<aspNetCore>` node, I get a different error:

> ## HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway
>
> **There was a connection error while trying to route the request.**
>
> **Detailed Error Information:**
>
> **Module**       AspNetCoreModule
>   **Notification**     ExecuteRequestHandler
>   **Handler**      aspNetCore
>   **Error Code**       0x80070490
>   **Requested URL**    http://localhost:80/IisTestApp
>   **Physical Path**    C:\Code\Sandbox\IisTestApp\IisTestApp
>   **Logon Method**     Anonymous
>   **Logon User**       Anonymous

The point being that the `AspNetCoreModule` throws the error this time, so it *is* being loaded and running some code.

Publishing to a separate folder and manually setting up the site in IIS (rather than relying on the default Visual Studio behavior of create an IIS website pointed at the "bin" folder) results in the same error message, although I get a slightly different `aspNetCore` node in the generated web.config file:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\IisTestApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
  <environmentVariables />
</aspNetCore>
```

**What is causing IIS to fail to run this application?**

I have tried re-installing .NET Core (SDK, runtime, and hosting component) but it did not help.

I also noticed several posts that mention installing the URL Rewrite module for IIS corrects this error (notably this: [HTTP Error 500.19 - IIS 7.5 Error 0x8007000d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532447/http-error-500-19-iis-7-5-error-0x8007000d)).  My web.config doesn't mention that module, but I tried installing it in case the AspNetCoreModule uses it under the covers.  This did not help in my situation.

Comment: I previously had .NET Core 5.0.1 Windows Hosting Bundle installed. For some reason it disappeared (either our server admins did it or MSFT did so automatically when server updates were done). I installed it again, and all is ok now. Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Having ruled out everything app-specific that I (and the many helpful commenters, especially [Daboul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6827240/daboul)) could think of, and having reviewed the visible IIS settings, I resorted to looking at the primary configuration file for IIS as a whole: applicationHost.config

Per [Introduction to ApplicationHost.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/introduction-to-applicationhostconfig), this file is located in `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config`.  Since the real application is working on a different machine at my office, I compared them using a diff program, and found that the following node was missing from my configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- ...lots of other stuff... -->
        <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
            <!-- ...lots of other stuff... -->

            <!--This "section" node for aspNetCore is the one that was missing-->
            <section name="aspNetCore" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Adding that one node resolved the error.

Oddly enough, the AspNetCoreModule itself is referenced multiple times later in the file. Since I haven't manually edited this file before, it seems possible that this was some kind of installation error when installing the AspNetCoreModule the first time.

It's very likely, if you encounter this issue, that the hosting bundle was installed **before** IIS.  There is now a warning in the documentation about this:

[Install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/hosting-bundle?view=aspnetcore-8.0#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle)

> If the Hosting Bundle is installed before IIS, the bundle installation must be repaired. Run the Hosting Bundle installer again after installing IIS.

This should accomplish the same thing as manually editing the ApplicationHost.config file as I did above.

Comment: THIS!!!! This helped me a bunch. Faced the same problem after having installed a newer version of .net core runtime. Tried everything, uninstalling all .net framework and .net core related sdk, runtimes and webhosting bundles and installing them again. Nothing worked. Found this, added the section and I was in business again. Thanks

Comment: I was pulling out my hair with the same basic issue (but with asp net core 3).
I believe that actual problem (in my case at least) was caused by installing the dotnet-hosting BEFORE IIS is installed.
Running a repair on the hosting installer (after installing IIS) fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 22):

Installing the .NET Core Hosting Bundle resolved the problem for me. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle) is a link to the .NET Core Hosting Bundle.

Using .NET Core 3.1

Comment: In my case I had to reinstall the bundle even when it was previously installed and the executables were there. It might happen if you turn on ISS in Windows Features after you install the bundle.

Comment: worked for me. win 10. dotnet 6

Comment: @Liero same for me.

Answer (score 8):

I tried using the above suggestion, but didn't work. So, I reinstalled the Asp Net Core Runtime Hosting in Administrator Mode, and my ApplicationHost.Config got corrected.

Comment: What is the error message that you see? Have a look at this tutorial https://windowswebhostingreview.com/asp-net-core-hosting-3-simple-steps-to-fix-502-5-error-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 7):

> Installing the .NET Core Hosting Bundle resolved the problem (like in answer upper)

In my case solution was simple, just restore Hosting bundle, and it helped.
Before restore I get `hresult 0x8007000d`. In iis for net core applications, modules were not loaded.

[image: some image for more info]

Answer (score 4):

If you install the *.NET Core Windows Hosting Bundle*, but the *AspNetCoreModule* still doesn't appear on your `applicationHost.config`, you can try to do what I did to solve my problem, after trying all the other solutions on SO and other places.

I found an `applicationHost.config` in another server that had those *AspNetCoreModule* lines and updated the file on the broken server.
Not sure why they were not being added by the .NET Core installation.

I added the line below under the `<globalModules>` section:

```
<add name="AspNetCoreModule" image="%SystemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\aspnetcore.dll" />
```

And this one under `<modules>`:

```
<add name="AspNetCoreModule" />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In dot core 5.0, I solved this error by installing hosting bundle 5.0.13

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/5.0

[image]

web.config

[image]

**As you can see in the web.config, it uses module "AspNetCoreModuleV2" which i have marked yellow in the download page**

Answer (score 1):

In my case the same error was caused by installing the dotnet-hosting BEFORE IIS is installed. Running a repair on the hosting installer (after installing IIS) fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

For this Error ==> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Error Code **0x8007000d** in IIS For .Net Core apllication .

go to below path and modify "applicationHost.config" in Notepad or any editor.

C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

in .config file find below line

```
<section name="webSocket" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

Add below line after above line ==>

```
<section name="aspNetCore" overrideModeDefault="Allow"/>
```

*Note:make sure you already installed .net core hosting bundle

Comment: Improve formatting

Answer (score 0):

Installing the .NET Core Hosting Bundle resolved the problem for me as well.

Current Version:
[Current .NET Core Hosting Bundle installer (direct download)](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/permalink/dotnetcore-current-windows-runtime-bundle-installer)

Answer (score -1):

I also get this error on dotnet core 3.1.

After removing wrapper section from web.config application starts work:

[image]

Changed to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
       <handlers>
          <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
       </handlers>
       <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ContactForm.Microservice.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
     </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Answer (score -1):

On Windows, we recommend installing the **Hosting Bundle**, which includes the .NET Runtime and IIS support.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0

[image]