# Configure web.config dotnet IIS

Tags: .net, .net-core, web-config, web.config-transform

I'm developing a dotnet application followed the passage of the reference and locally on Ubuntu it's all ok, however now I try to publish to my windows server and when access to route configurable them myself from the following error:[image]

In the reference he will tell me to delete the malformed element in my web.config, but I do not know what I'm doing wrong, can someone help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\connect-app.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" hostingModel="inprocess" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Click the link "View more information" at the bottom

Comment: I clicked it and I saw the information telling me to remove the incorrect formation in my web.config, but I don't know what's wrong

Comment: <handlers>
     `<add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>` tyr like this removing `V2`

Comment: V2 is because my framework is dotnet 3.1, without it publish gives an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways that you could end up in this error.

- The ASP.NET Core Module v2 was not properly installed and configured.

  - Install the ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/permalink/dotnetcore-current-windows-runtime-bundle-installer)
- Verify that the AspNetCoreModuleV2 in the IIS Modules
- Sometimes, the file system may restricts the access to some paths for the Application Pool

  - Try adding the Application Pool Identity to the respective
    File/Folder

    ICACLS C:\StatusApp\ /grant "IIS AppPool\YourAppPool:F"
- Put your Hosting as "Out of Process" and see if the .NET Core
  Apllication is properly instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for 500.19 IIS with the 0x8007000d error code that you provided.  The articles that I found state that this happens when a module is missing and / or hasn't been installed yet.

Double-check that the ASP.NET Core module for IIS is installed on the system with the web.config and go from there.

*Sources*:

[The Horrible Story of Publishing NET Core Web Apps for Beginners](https://blog.lextudio.com/the-horrible-story-of-publishing-net-core-web-apps-for-beginners-6121662dd8c4)

[MSDN - Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle)

[ASP.NET Forums](https://forums.asp.net/t/2121840.aspx?ASP+Net+Core+Publish+HTTP+Error+500+19+Internal+Server+Error)

[IIS Forums](https://forums.iis.net/t/1176834.aspx)

---

edit:

What's in your ApplicationHost.config file?  Do you have `<section name="aspNetCore" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />`?

*Source*: [Error 0x8007000d when running ASP.NET Core app in IIS despite AspNetCoreModule being installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984884/error-0x8007000d-when-running-asp-net-core-app-in-iis-despite-aspnetcoremodule-b)

Comment: I followed Microsoft's tutorial to get to this point, and I've seen some articles talking about how bad this error log is.
so I posted here to see if anyone has anything more concrete about installing the parameters they have in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enabled ASP.NET feature for IIS

[Install IIS and ASP.NET modules in Windows 2016](https://help.genesys.com/cic/mergedProjects/wh_tr/mergedProjects/wh_tr_web_administrator/desktop/win2016_install_iis_and_asp.net_modules.htm)

Try uninstalling and installing IIS runtime support (ASP.NET Core Module v2)

Answer (score 0):

**1. URL rewriting** is not configured correctly or not properly installed

**Error 0x8007000d** Maybe happens if your URL rewriting module is missing in the web.config  or proper version is not installed.

Make Sure to **install** URL rewriting module via web platform installer.([REFERENCE](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite))

**2. check stdlog**

You can also take a look at stdlog text file which is enabled in the web.config to see what exactly happens.

**3.ASP.NET Core Module v2**

finally as other users suggested make sure The ASP.NET Core Module v2 is installed and configured correctly

Answer (score 0):

My issue was due to the fact the installation of the IIS was done after ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle. This did not install the ASP.NET Core Module v2 properly.

You should have the folder C:\Program Files\IIS

I needed to repair the installation of the hosting bundle and then the ASP.NET Core Module v2 install was included.

[image: IIS folder under Program Files]