# Getting Error 500.19 when deploying .NET Core 3 on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: .net-core, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

When deploying a REST API based on ASP.NET Core 3.1 in Windows Server 2012 R2 it throws the following error:

[HTTP ERROR 500.19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8M91.png)

I installed

- .net core SDK
- .net core runtime
- .net core windows server hosting
- c ++ redistributable
- KB2999226

The appPool is configured as follows:

- .Net version: no managed code
- Channeling mode: integrated
- Enable 32-bit app: true (if it was false when executing the App, the appPool would stop)

The folder where the site points to has all the permissions.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html Run a report and see what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you. Install and run the application and report that the "NET CORE Bundle" module needs to be installed, since it is already installed. Will I have to define something in IIS to be able to use it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 500.19 with 0x8007000d when running ASP.NET Core app in IIS despite AspNetCoreModule being installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984884/error-500-19-with-0x8007000d-when-running-asp-net-core-app-in-iis-despite-aspnet)

Comment: could you please share your web.conifg file? you could try to uninstall the .net core runtime and hosting bundle from your machine and install it again from this link based on your version. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1. another thing is assign iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the site folder