# .net core HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, http-error

I am using .net core 2.2, and when deploying IIS, the following error occurs.
[image]

I added permission for the file and also installed .net core sdk.
(SDK 2.1.811, .NET Core Runtime 2.1.23)

What causes these errors?

web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>
  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\JbeAdminApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Hi @김세림,have you install the `.NET Core Hosting Bundle`?

Comment: Make sure you are following this [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: @Yinqiu yes. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1 
I installed the sdk and runtime bundle from the site.

Comment: After installing the bundle, you must either restart your server or completely stop and restart the IIS service.

Comment: @Yinqiu 
After installing the bundle I shut down and restarted. But I still get the same error.

Comment: There are many reasons for this error, first you can try to install [IIS URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite), or you can refer to the solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984884/error-500-19-with-0x8007000d-when-running-asp-net-core-app-in-iis-despite-aspnet). If it still doesn't work, then you can reinstall .NET core or do a repair.

Comment: as mentioned, there are a lot of factors that could finalize to this error. Are you seeing any relevant errors in application logs?

Comment: Run a report to rule out common mistakes, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: Can you show me your web.comfig file? and I suggest you not  publish the site on desktop user does not have permission to access desktop folder, you can put it in the D drive or somewhere else.