# How to I resolve this error "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error" Error Code 0x8007000d

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

[image]**HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error**
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid

Detailed Error Information:

> Module       IIS Web Core Notification       BeginRequest Handler    Not yet
> determined Error Code    0x8007000d Config Error      Config File
> \?\D:\Projects\Main\New\EHRMV9_CR_23.12.2020_01\web.config
>
> Requested URL    http://localhost:80/EHRMV9_1/home/index
>
> Physical Path
> D:\Projects\Main\New\EHRMV9_CR_23.12.2020_01\home\index
>
> Logon Method     Not yet determined Logon User       Not yet determined
>
> Config Source:    -1:
> 0

Answer (score 0):

First please check if you have installed .NET Core Hosting Bundle, If not, please install it according to the link below:

[Install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle)

Do you use url rewriting in your project? If yes, please check if URL Rewrite is installed.

[URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Finally, please check your web.config file to see if there is a problem, you can refer to this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54987397/13336642

Comment: I installed the URL Rewrite, then after the problem is solved.Thank you @samwu,

Comment: I'm so glad that the problem has been resolved. It is so appreciated if you can accept my solution as answer.