# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error , Error Code: 0x8007000d - plesk

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, hosting, plesk

I want to publish my ASP.Net Core MVC project with Plesk hosting (GoDaddy), the project works without any error locally, but when I publish the project, I get this error, how can I fix it?

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
> accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
> invalid.
>
> Module IIS Web Core Notification Unknown Handler Not yet determined
> Error Code 0x8007000d Config Error Config File
> ?\G:\PleskVhosts\kodbozuk.com\httpdocs\web.config

This is my `web.config` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\KodBozuk.WEB.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="outofprocess" />.
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <compilation tempDirectory="G:\PleskVhosts\kodbozuk.com\tmp" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Although I've tried to make various changes to the `web.config` file, I could not get any results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [- HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error , Error Code: 0x8007000d -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76607571/http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-error-code-0x8007000d)

Comment: yes, I forgot to delete it and shared it twice when no one replied.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP Error 500.19 and error code : 0x80070021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048486/http-error-500-19-and-error-code-0x80070021)

Comment: no my error code:0x8007000d and also my problem about plesk-web.config :/

Comment: I think it may be the same as IIS, and it also needs to install [.NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-7.0.8-windows-hosting-bundle-installer). Of course, it could also be a problem with the URL Rewrite module. You can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66866082/18789859).

Comment: I found [this article](https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/dotnet-application-hosting-in-plesk/) on Plesk's official website, it mentions [.NET Toolkit](https://www.plesk.com/extensions/dot-net/). Do you publish your application based on it?

Comment: Try fixes from this related question: [HTTP Error 500.19 - IIS 7.5 Error 0x8007000d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532447/http-error-500-19-iis-7-5-error-0x8007000d). Note that in case of Plesk, you may need to do this operation via its web UI.